# How do I retrieve multiple paragraphs after a ID tag with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to retrieve all relevant paragraphs after a specific tag using Beautifulsoup. Currently I can retrieve the first paragraph without issue but all attempts either return an error or an empty string. The html I am working with is (this is mostly just the Las Vegas Wikipedia page after the "Tourism" header):

```
<h3>
    <span id="Tourism" class="mw-headline">Tourism</span>
</h3>
<div class="thumb tright">....</div>
<div class="thumb tright">....</div>
<div class="thumb tright">....</div>
<div class="thumb tright">....</div>
<p>Text I can get</p>
<p>Text that I cant get</p>
<h4>....</h4>
```

my program:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class WikiScrape(Resource):
    def get(self, location):
        tour_page = requests.get(
            url = f"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{location}"
        )
        soup = BeautifulSoup(tour_page.content, 'html.parser')
        title = soup.find(id = "Tourism")
        para = title.find_next('p').get_text(strip = True)

api.add_resource(WikiScrape, '/<location>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

I use cURL to call this program.

I have tried retrieving all the paragraphs after the ID tag using `title.find_all` and this returns an empty list. I have tried to iterate through the returned list and print all text in it but only get empty strings.
I just tried changing my code within the class to this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(tour_page.content, 'html.parser')
title = soup.find('span',{'id': 'Tourism'})
paras = [x.contents[0] for x in title.findAllNext('p')]
return jsonify({'message': f'{title.string}: {paras}'})
```

This gives me a ton of unusable parts of the paragraphs but its heading in the direction I'm meaning to go.

Working code based on help from Berklay Kaplan:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class WikiScrape(Resource):
    def get(self, location):
        tour_page = requests.get(
            url = f"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{location}"
        )
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(tour_page.content, 'html.parser')
        title = soup.find('h3', text='Tourism')
        paras = ''
        
        for sibling in title.find_next_siblings():
            if sibling.name == 'p':
                paras = paras + sibling.text.strip()
            elif sibling.name == 'h4':
                break

        return jsonify({'message': f'{paras}'})

api.add_resource(WikiScrape, '/<location>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `findAllNext('p')`, can you try implementing a while loop that iterates through the sibling elements of the title? It should append the text of each paragraph to the `paras` list. Also, `<span id="Tourism" class="mw-headline">Tourism</span>` is not a direct sibling to the paragraphs you're looking for.

Comment: Ok this actually got me a little bit closer, I had to use `get_text(strip=True)` to make it more readable, but currently its just returning everything on the webpage after the ID, I'm just trying to get the specific following paragraphs.

Comment: I think the paragraphs you are looking for are not the direct siblings of the ```<span id="Tourism" class="mw-headline">Tourism</span>``` element>. Can you try finding the nearest header ```<h3> or <h4>``` and then loop through its siblings.

Comment: It took me a minute to get to, but I did get it to work. I changed the 'title' variable to `title = soup.find('h3', text='Tourism')` and created a loop that will iterate through the next siblings and return what I want. I'll edit the post to reflect the changes.